# Is there a better way to conceal armor?

Tags: stealth, equipment, spycraft

Is there a way to raise the notice/search DC of armor past what is listed in the armor table?  As far as I can tell, the only way to make armor hard to notice is to wear armor that is listed "as clothing" or use a Proteus mod to literally make it clothing.

There's got to be a better way to do that though, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Miniaturization, so that your belt buckle projects some sort of force field.

The Proteus mod is great for things that transform into other things, which to me always felt like a vehicle kind of property.

In a way it's realistic: armor looks bulky, or makes noise, or sticks out.

Comment: The unfortunate part about the Miniature Gear Pick mechanism is that "[c]oncealing or readying the Gadget’s [gear pick] requires a number of full actions equal to the chosen gear pick’s Caliber" (279), making it a fine option if given a chance to prepare but not so great if one's trying to *stay* undercover.